# Suspicious Dots

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

### 1984 =

[image: Lots of dots]

### Message:

[image: Lots and lots of dots and dots]

> u l g i o w y m s m u e b x g z g e n t<

(Note that dot sizes and distances are not part of the puzzle.)

Comment: What are you asking though?

Comment: Well, saying that would make the puzzle much easier.

Comment: In that case tag enigmatic-puzzle

Comment: is it intended that some of the dots are very slightly different sizes than others? (For example the third grouping of the "1984" set - the red and gray dots on the right are slightly smaller than the red dots on the left).  Or is that an accidental result of however the image was generated?

Comment: No, that was just an accident.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> waterfall

Reasoning:

> Dots in groups of 7 (2 + 3 + 2 vertical dots) represent a **7-segment digital display** (e.g. 8 = all dots red, 9 = lower left gray, etc.).
> Hence the bottom message reads **2539** which we need to substitute with corresponding letters of alphabet to get **beci**.
>  This in turn is a key for **Vigenère cipher** to turn the encrypted text into "**theansweriswaterfall**".

Comment: any chance you have a link that explains how to decrypt such a cipher?  I'm completely at a loss as to how you arrived at the final answer.

Comment: http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/autokey-cipher/